# app.php not working in symfony2.3

Tags: php, symfony-2.3

I create a symfony 2.3 project. some times all the pages shows 500 error. app.php also shows error. i dont know why can any one help

www.dotcue.in/sandp/web/app.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 353ms]

Comment: 1. does app_dev.php work? 2. Do you use FirePHP or ChromePHP?

Comment: no app_dev.php also not working

Comment: not for login all pages shows the same error

Comment: we can not see it working if it requires login. What do you mean on "sometimes" working? What does it depend on?

Comment: i working locally localhost url doest support by stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark here and conclude that it is one of the following problems:

1. The prod cache is out of date, to fix it run: `php app/console --env=prod cache:clear`
2. The vendors are missing, to fix it run: `php composer.phar install`

If it is a problem when code that you have written however, we need to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Overly big `HTTP headers`** (e.x. 4 kB) can cause this error depending on the hosting server. `ChromePHP` sends all of its data in HTTP headers. (you wrote you use ChromePHP)

Try turning it off or lowering the data sent with ChromePHP. Did it help?